# Rubber Keg Boot Glue Recommendation

Tags: keg, corny-keg, kegs

I just bought two reconditioned 5 gal pin lock kegs. When I filled them up with hot water to clean them out I noticed that the rubber boot at the top of one of them was completely loose - it's only being held on by the poppet valve stems.  I plan to remove the poppet valves and try to glue the boot back on... Does anyone know what type of glue would work best?

Comment: I'd like to know this too, but for the base of one of my kegs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid nails or rubber cement would work nicely. Make sure that you remove the 'boot' and remove all of the old residue that may be stuck on. I would probably run some coarse grit sandpaper over that afterwards just to create a rough surface for the cement to bind to. That isn't necessary but make sure you clean the area at least.

Comment: Going to go with the liquid nails...I agree with you that I should clean it well before, but I'm lazy so I'm going to just try squirting it in from every angle and putting something heavy on top for a day or two.  If that doesn't work I'll take it apart and do it right.

Comment: Took everything apart (it was easier than I thought it would be), cleaned and sanded the indside of the boot and outside of the keg with 60 grit sand paper, and used an entire syringe of gorilla glue two-part epoxy. I flipped the keg upside down and sat on it to make sure the boot was seated tight and gave it a couple of hours to cure, and it seems to have worked great!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked! Just like new.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of people using the adhesive for car mouldings to do this.  They said its available at most autoparts stores.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard [liquid nails](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001C02FW8) does a nice job.